# Land concentration in Columbia

Tags: economy, agriculture, political-economy, south-america

I am looking for elaboration for the following passage, which I found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_reforms_by_country#Colombia):

"In 1968 and 1969 alone, the INCORA issued more than 60,000 land titles to farmers and workers. Despite this, Matsetela (2000) stated that **the process was then halted and the situation began to reverse itself**, as the subsequent violent actions of drug lords, paramilitaries, guerrillas and opportunistic large landowners severely contributed to a **renewed concentration of land and to the displacement of small landowners**".

In particular, I am looking for more details about the process by which concentration of land has occured in Columbia.

I searched in Google scholar, both by the name "Matsetela" and by subject, but found no relevant results.